# What do I do with prebuilt library .so.0 file?

Tags: libraries

I have downloaded a precompiled library for which the filename is in the format:

`<name>.so.0`

I gather this some kind of versioning? How do I use the library - do I need to use a tool to extract it? I think the program will only look for `<name>` when looking for the file..

Answer (score 4):

Compiled libraries are automatically loaded, when a binary is executed. For this, the locations defined in /etc/ld.so.conf are checked. On most distributions you should put the library in `/usr/local/lib`, where libraries not installed by the package manager are stored.

If you don't want to install the library system wide (or don't have root access), you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the folder containing your .so-file when running your program:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/folder_with_so_file ./yourprogram
```

Regarding the version number: if your program explicitly looks for `.so` without a number, create a symlink (also in the lib folder):

```
ln -s <name>.so.0 name.so
```

Most libraries keep the file with the most specific version number and create symlinks for the major version and the non-versioned name (for example on my system `/usr/lib` contains the files `libjpeg.so`,  `/usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62` and `/usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0`, the former two being symlinks to the latter)